# android - Implement DrawerLayout with BottomNavigationView and FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout, drawerlayout, android-bottomnavigationview

Im currently creating an app, which has a BottomNavigationView and a FrameLayout for fragments. I would like to implement a DrawerLayout or Hamburger Menu too, however, as said in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do4vb0MdLFY) video

> A DrawerLayout should only contain two views, one for the ActivityFragment and one for the NavigationView

Is it possible then to implement the DrawerLayout while having the BottomNavigationView? If yes, how?

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayoutFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorSecondaryDark"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottomnavgation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That whole `<ConstraintLayout>` would be the main content – i.e., the first child – inside the `<DrawerLayout>`. Your drawer `View` – e.g., a `<NavigationView>` – would be the second child within the `<DrawerLayout>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement the DrawerLayout while having the BottomNavigationView, try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btm_nav"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tool_bar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/btm_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/nav"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_dr"
        app:menu="@menu/nav"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```